# Windows running on HDD very slow

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, operating-systems

Ever since I am dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu I get a lot of lags on Windows. My Windows takes extremely long to boot and I often get lags when I am switching the active window or I try to start a new application.

I don't know that much about computers so when I installed Ubuntu I accidentally uninstalled Windows and I reinstalled it onto my HDD (it was installed on my SSD before) and since then it has been running very slow.

I don't know if installing Windows again on a SSD could solve my problems but I don't have any space left on it so before wiping my system once again I wanted to know if it could actually be the reason for my problems.

I would be grateful for every help and thanks in advance :)

Comment: The perceived difference in speed between Windows 10 running from a HDD vs. from an SDD can easily be 10:1, 100:1 or more. This is due to the fact, that Windows 10 is extremly inefficient in its use of file system resources.

Comment: @EugenRieck: This is nonsense.

Comment: @harrymc Is it? The OP has exactly that problem - perceived laggines of WIndows on a HDD, when it was fine on an SSD. It is also my experience from 1000+ Windows installs on SSDs and HDDs and 10.000+ Linux installs on HDDs and SSDs.

Comment: The only explanation possible is if you are missing drivers for your hardware. Some information about your computer's model and whether you are using Microsoft generic drivers would be helpful.

Comment: @harrymc I can't really tell you the drivers but besides my Graphics card drivers I haven't changed anything. I'll look into the drivers. but it is possible that such a drastic change is caused by the HDD?

Comment: Not enough data for an opinion yet. Need more info about your hardware and measures of the observed lags.

Comment: Not seeing anywhere where it was specified whether the original not slow Windows installation was on a HDD or SSD.

Comment: @DawnBenton yup you're right, changed it now :)

Answer (score 1):

If you had Windows installed originally on a SSD and you installed it now on a HD... well, there's your answer.

An HD is a mechanical device; the disc has actually to spin and the head has to physically move to read the data. A SSD is an electric device. The difference in speed among them is in the orders of magnitude. You'll notice this even more when it's booting, since that's when Windows (or any other OS) has to read more files from the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by PaulJ](https://superuser.com/a/1388765/194694) is correct, but I think it's worth expanding.

There are three main reasons why SSDs feel snappier than HDDs.

1. **Sequential access speed difference.** Toshiba P300 1 TB (7200 rpm HDD) has sequential read speed of 160 MB/s, while Samsung 850 Evo 1 TB (SATA SSD) scores 420 MB/s. SSDs are just faster.
2. **Random access speed difference.** 1.13 MB/s for Toshiba P300 and 65 MB/s for Samsung 850 Evo. Data is located in specific places on HDD's platters. Accessing it requires waiting for platters to rotate and head to move so that their positions match. Accessing a lot of files simultaneously or sequentially if they aren't located nearby each other stresses HDDs a lot, because they do a lot of seeking and not much reading/writing. SSDs don't suffer from this because they have no moving parts and constant access times.
3. **Nonuniform speed across drive.** HDD platters store data outside in, ie. data tracks start near the platter's edge and approach the center, so the outer tracks are longer and pack more data. HDDs try to maintain constant angular rotation speed (typically 7200 rpm in desktops and 5400 rpm in laptops). As a result, reads/writes to outer tracks (beginning of a drive) are faster. This effect has a number of curious consequences on spinning drives. If your OS is installed on a small partition at the beginning of a drive, it won't benefit from NCQ (HDD's reordering of tasks to reduce head movements and delays). On the other hand, if you have a single large partition, its filesystem will distribute data across platters, possibly placing some in slower inner areas.